# XPATH get Entrys with Value 1 on 5. Position of Attribute

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a XML File:

```
<attribute id="1" export="01101">
  <value>test</value>
</attribute>
```

Now, I want all Entrys, where the Number is 1 on 5th. Digit in Attribute export.
I use PHP for the Query.
I have tried this, but doesen't work:

```
$xpath->query("//attribute/@export[substring(., 4, 1) = '1]");
```

Any Ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You are missing one ' character there.  Might that be the problem?  Looks OK to me otherwise.

Comment: There are no elements nor attributes involved in the XML example you give that are named *Entry*. Please fix your question, it is not clear what you're asking for. **DOMNode**s that have names are  **DOMElement** or **DOMAttr** only. For which nodes are you wanting here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One quote is missing, as @HaukurHaf pointed out. So, it should be:

```
$xpath->query("//attribute/@export[substring(., 4, 1) = '1']");
```

However, this is not the only problem. According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring) of `substring`

> As in other XPath functions, the position is not zero-based. The first
>   character in the string has a position of 1, not 0.

so, the final version should be:

```
$xpath->query("//attribute/@export[substring(., 5, 1) = '1']");
```

Comment: Hmm, with so much *obvious* typo-potential (and a nice off-by-one error!), why didn't @Gerd accept this as the answer already?

Answer (score 1):

Xpath counts from 1, not from zero, so you should write 5 for 5th digit.

```
//attribute/@export[substring(., 5, 1) ='1']
```